# How to show that the plane $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ minus the non-negative $x-$axis is homeomorphic to the entire plane $\mathbb{R^{2}}$

Tags: general-topology

I first tried to map everything not on the line $y=0$ to itself and then extend the ray $\{(x,y): x\in (-\infty,0),y=0\}$ to the whole of $(-\infty,\infty),y=0$ by using $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{2x}{1-x}+1)\right)\right)$. But I don't think that this will be continuous albeit a bijection. This problem is from Viro.

Explicitly the set is $\{(x,y):y^{2}+|x|>x\}$

Can anyone please suggest how I should approach this?

Comment: One approach: If you were deleting the non-positive $x$-axis, the standard branch of the complex square root would map you to the right half plane, which may be easier to work with.  Therefore, try $\sqrt{-x-iy}$ for the original problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x>0\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&(x^2-y^2,2xy)\end{array}$$is a homeomorphism from $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x>0\}$ onto $\Bbb R^2\setminus(-\infty,0]$; just use the fact that $(x+yi)^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi$. And$$\begin{array}{rccc}g\colon&\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x>0\}\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&(e^x,y)\end{array}$$is a homeomorphism from $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x>0\}$ onto $\Bbb R^2$. So…

Comment: Brilliant answer. Can you please tell me how to intuitively think about such maps . I am very new to topology. I was solving the excercises in Viro. there were a total of 12 problems amongst which this was one. All the others were doable...sometimes by taking polar coordinates. but I was stuck at this.

Comment: @jasnee I think it should be $e^{x}$

Comment: Oh wait....he edited it .

Comment: @jasnee No. It was a typo. I meant to write $(e^x,y)$, but I wrote $(e^xx,y)$ instead.

Comment: @NicholasFlammel I don't have a general way to think about problems such as this one. In each situation, I try to think of a map that will solve the problem at hand.

Comment: I guess it will come from more practice . Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

If you do this in two stages, it becomes completely transparent.

First, every point in your set can be represented by the complex number $re^{i\theta}$, where $r\ne 0$ and $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$. Map your set continuously to the open upper half-plane with $re^{i\theta}\mapsto re^{i\theta/2}$ (rather like [closing a fan](https://youtu.be/_BmfaOwHVt4?t=10) from $360^\circ$ to $180^\circ$).

And now map the $y$-coordinate continuously from $(0,\infty)$ to $\Bbb R$. I see you already know how to do this.

Comment: Very intuitive answer, nice!