# $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,0) \mid x \in [0,\infty) \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[How to show that the plane $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ minus the non-negative $x-$axis is homeomorphic to the entire plane $\mathbb{R^{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265093/how-to-show-that-the-plane-mathbbr2-minus-the-non-negative-x-axis-is-h)

In order to attempt this answer by my own I am trying to do this. I did

$$f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (x,0) \mid x \in [0,\infty) \}$$

such that $f(x,y) = (-\exp(-x),y)$, but this is homeomorphic with

$$P = \{ (x,y) \mid y \neq 0, x \in (-\infty,0) \} \cup \{ (x,0) \mid x \in (-\infty,-1) \}$$

but how can I show this space $P$ is homeomorphic with $\{(x,y) \mid x < 0 \}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax, and in the future you should do the same. If you could please double check that I translated your question correctly, it was hard in places to know exactly what you were intending.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thank you

Comment: By Riemann mapping theorem, the domain is biholomorphic to the open disc and rhe open disc is homeomorphic to the plane.

Comment: If we apply $z \to -z$ to the set we get exactly the main branch of complex logarithm, do we not?

Answer (score 1):

The map $\sqrt{z}$ is defined on your set and defines a homeomorphism onto an open half-plane.